# Cosmos DB UDF Convert an Object to an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

There is a nested property with unknown field names, need to be able to get the value of the property fields into an array to check if they contact a specific value.
{
"props": {
"unknownFieldName1": "A",
"unknownFieldName2": "B",
"unknownFieldName3": "C",
}
}

Simple Javascript code works
Object.values(props).indexOf("C") and returns 2

This syntax will not work in Cosmos UDF.

Any ideas or alternate solutions?

Answer (score 0):

function isValueInProperty(props, value){

```
for(var key in props){
        
        if (props[key] === value)
        {
        return true;
        }
}
return false;
```

}